# java hangman - counting correct user guesses

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I'm building a hangman/word guessing game that uses an array to check if the user input matches a letter in the word (that they are attempting to guess). Trying to keep track of the number of times the user guesses correctly (using the occurence variable), but whenever the code is run it counts twice.

So let's say the word is "alpaca"...
User guesses the letter "p".
Occurence equals "2" (should be "1")

Why is it counting twice and how do I fix it?

```html
while (indexCount < wordLength) {
                result = word1.indexOf(guess, indexCount);

                if (result != -1) {
                    occurence++;
                    //wordArr[result] = guess + " ";
                }
                indexCount++;
                

            }
```

P.S. I hope this makes sense as I am not the best at explaining things.
I can post the full code if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increment `occurence` by the number of occurrences of the guessed letter, it should be:

```
indexCount = 0;
while (indexCount < wordLength) {
    result = word1.indexOf(guess, indexCount);
    if (result > -1) {
        occurence++;
        indexCount = result + 1; // current occurrence is at index result, so search for
                                 // next occurrence starting at index result + 1
    } else {
        break; // no more occurrences
    }                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the while loop condition you are using. Your occurence gets incremented when indexCount=0 and indexCount=1; Probably you wanted to do this

```
indexCount = indexCount + result;
```